# Keep typing on generic type factory

Tags: typescript, redux, types, typesafe-actions

I'm trying to create an request action factory. Each request action should have a `request`, `success` and `failure`.

Currently I'm creating actions this way (with `typesafe-actions` package):

```
const loadList = {
  request: () => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_REQUEST),
  success: (data: CampaignState) => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS, data),
  failure: () => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_FAILURE),
};
```

With that `typescript` can infer the type of each object allowing typing and autocomplete like this:

```
loadList.request().type
```

But I found myself writing everywhere the `request`, `success` and `failure` boilerplate, so I think to create a factory to build this to enforce the pattern and facilitate the writing, something like this:

```
const loadList = new RequestAction(
  () => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_REQUEST),
  (data: CampaignState) => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS, data),
  () => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_FAILURE),
);
```

The point is that with every approach I tried I always fall on a case that I need to define the type of the constructor params of the `RequestAction` class, but it's defined by the overloads of the `action` and I don't have access to that type on constructor.

Is there a way to infer the type of the parameters or maybe a smarter way to do that factory keeping the type of the actions?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very easy to get proper inference on this by making `RequestAction` a generic class with separate generic type parameters for each action creator function.  If the class has some internal logic then you'll want to constrain the types using `extends`.   But for type safety, all you need is this:

```
class RequestAction<R, S, F> {
  constructor(
    public readonly request: R,
    public readonly success: S,
    public readonly failure: F
  ) {}
}
```

I am getting proper inference on the action creator arguments, the created actions, and the action type constants.

```
import { action } from "typesafe-actions";

class RequestAction<R, S, F> {
  constructor(
    public readonly request: R,
    public readonly success: S,
    public readonly failure: F
  ) {}
}

const CampaignsRequestTypes = {
  LOAD_REQUEST: "LOAD_REQUEST",
  LOAD_SUCCESS: "LOAD_SUCCESS",
  LOAD_FAILURE: "LOAD_FAILURE"
} as const;

interface CampaignState {
  name: string;
}

const loadList = new RequestAction(
  () => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_REQUEST),
  (data: CampaignState) => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS, data),
  () => action(CampaignsRequestTypes.LOAD_FAILURE)
);

const type = loadList.request().type; // type: "LOAD_REQUEST"

// requires that success() be called with CampaignState
const success = loadList.success({ name: "" }); // type: { type: "LOAD_SUCCESS";  payload: CampaignState; }
```

This is an old question and you probably want to switch over to [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), if you haven't already, as that removes the need to define all of the action type constants separately.